# Не работает событие на клик у класса

Tags: javascript

столкнулся с проблемой,когда использую события по id или queryselector,то оно выполняется,но при использовании события по классу или по тэгу,событие не выполняется,почему?

```js
    document.getElementById("next").onclick=function () {
        alert("1");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <p class="text">123</p>
    <button id="prev">prev</button>
    <button id="next">next</button>




        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', function () {alert("1")});`

Comment: Событие по классу - очень интересно. Думаю, это означает `getElementsByClassName`. Если так, то  это потому что у вас возвращается коллекция элементов. Читайте про массивы.

Comment: я так и понял,но мне не понятно как сделать событие на определенный класс

Comment: Поэтому я советую вам почитать про массивы, циклы.

Comment: как понимаю нужно все элементы класса прогонять через цикл?

Comment: Да, вам необходимо использовать цикл.